# Select with case when + join, MYSQL

Tags: mysql, left-join, case

Guys are you able to help me in this below case?
I'm wanna to select and change the results:

My code looks as follow:

```
$USER_STORY = $this->lang->line('application_status_change_user_story');
$TO_DO = $this->lang->line('application_status_change_to_do');
$IN_PROGRESS = $this->lang->line('application_status_change_in_progress');
$DONE = $this->lang->line('application_status_change_done');
$UNDONE = $this->lang->line('application_status_change_undone');

    SELECT sum(project_has_tasks.estimated_hours) as val, project_has_tasks.name, 
    project_has_tasks.start_date,
    project_has_tasks.due_date,
    project_has_tasks.progress,
    TIME_FORMAT(SEC_TO_TIME(sum(project_has_tasks.time_spent)),'%k.%i') 
    as total_time, users.id, users.firstname, users.lastname,(case
             when 'user_story' then '$USER_STORY'
             when 'to_do' then '$TO_DO'
             when 'in_progress' then '$IN_PROGRESS'
             when 'done' then '$DONE'
             when 'undone' then '$UNDONE'
             else 'NOTHING'
          end) as status
    FROM project_has_tasks
    RIGHT JOIN users ON project_has_tasks.user_id
     = users.id WHERE project_has_tasks.project_id ='99' 
    GROUP BY project_has_tasks.id ASC
```

What to modify to get a proper results? Now I'm getting NOTHING in status column, but no errors.

Comment: I think your case statement is wrong, There no condition is checking so only it return the last else statement

Comment: The statuses are in project_has_tasks in status column. What to add to tell the select that I wanna to pick up the statuses from project_has_tasks.status?

Comment: case
             when status = 'user_story' then '$USER_STORY'
             when status = 'to_do' then '$TO_DO'
             when status = 'in_progress' then '$IN_PROGRESS'
             when status = 'done' then '$DONE'
             when status = 'undone' then '$UNDONE'
             else 'NOTHING'
          end)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your case statement is wrong, There no condition is checking so only it return the last else statement

```
SELECT sum(project_has_tasks.estimated_hours) as val, project_has_tasks.name, 
project_has_tasks.start_date,
project_has_tasks.due_date,
project_has_tasks.progress,
TIME_FORMAT(SEC_TO_TIME(sum(project_has_tasks.time_spent)),'%k.%i') 
as total_time, users.id, users.firstname, users.lastname,(case
         when project_has_tasks.status = 'user_story' then '$USER_STORY'
         when project_has_tasks.status = 'to_do' then '$TO_DO'
         when project_has_tasks.status = 'in_progress' then '$IN_PROGRESS'
         when project_has_tasks.status = 'done' then '$DONE'
         when project_has_tasks.status = 'undone' then '$UNDONE'
         else 'NOTHING'
      end) as status
FROM project_has_tasks
RIGHT JOIN users ON project_has_tasks.user_id
 = users.id WHERE project_has_tasks.project_id ='99' 
GROUP BY project_has_tasks.id ASC
```